# Google Docs PDF's Pagging and Zooming Controls is not visible in android webview

Tags: android, android-webview, google-docs-api, android-websettings

I am using Google Docs to show PDF in Web view , the PDF is open properly in android web view but controls of Google Docs is not visible on top of PDF

This is my code .

```
private WebView mWebView;
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mWebView = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());

    mWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="
            + "http://dispart.fr/ART/31/197/pwg_high/art3119712_fdff01.pdf");
    setContentView(mWebView);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you found the solution? Please post if yes.